# aws-sdk s3 generates Incomplete signed url when called inside ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, pre-signed-url

I am trying to generate a presignedurl to get an object from s3 inside a container via Fargate task. It has `s3:GetObject` and `s3:PutObject` permission. When I call `s3.getSignedUrl(params)` it only returns `https://s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/` instead of the full signed url here is the code that I am using inside the container

```
const getFileUrl = async (key, bucketName) => {
  try {
    const s3 = new aws.S3();
    const url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', { Bucket: bucketName, Key: key });
    return url;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you assigned an IAM role to the ECS task role, or only to the task execution role? That is a common mistake. ECS tasks have two separate IAM roles, one for ECS execution, and one for the code that runs inside the task.

Comment: I just checked I am using the same role as task execution role and task role. And that role had the s3: permissions in it.  Is this a permission related issue?

Comment: Are you sure `key` and `bucketName` aren't empty or something?

Comment: Yes I have checked them the key and the bucket name weren't empty.

Comment: It really doesn't seem possible that the code in your question is returning that URL. Sorry I don't know how to help more. I suggest adding more debugging to make sure the error is in the section of code you think it is.